# What is better, macros or inline functions for square or sqrt of constants?

Tags: c

In algorithms I am using such constants:

```
sqrt(3)
pow(M_PI, 2)
```

Unfortunately the C preprocessor is not smart enough to pre-compute these constants. Is there any additional layer of preprocessing that can be used with GCC or any other C compiler?

I have currently implemented these two constants as:

```
#define SQRT3  1.7320508
#define PIPI   (M_PI*M_PI)
```

But I feel using obscure names like `PIPI` (which also means pee in french) is not the best solution. I think it would be better to write:

```
inline float square(float x) {
   return x * x;
}
```

However this is not possible for the square root. At least, I can get sufficient an approximation with this:

```
inline float sqrt_approx(float z)
{
    int val_int = *(int*)&z;
    val_int -= 1 << 23;
    val_int >>= 1;
    val_int += 1 << 29; 
    return *(float*)&val_int;
}
```

Unfortunately, and again, the compiler is not smart enough to interpret `sqrt_approx(3)` as 1.73

Is there a better way to deal with these C limitations?

We are in the year 2015, we have rovers that roams on Mars and we are still dealing with C compilers that makes us feel in the 80s. Am I wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to name the constant `PI_SQUARED` instead? I don't see what's wrong with defining a short number of constants, given they are not expected to change a lot.

Comment: Where do you need them computed by the preprocessor?

Comment: @moooeeeep Well, this has to be seen as a more general example. I feel more readable to see `sqrt(3)/2` somewhere in a code than `HALF_SQRT3`.

Comment: macro defined "constant" are usefull for defining values a compile time without touching the code, so in that regard they are useful, for your case the `const` qualifier is better suited

Comment: @coin : I edited my answer completely as it wasn't reflecting the truth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because those constants are *true constants* (not to be confused with `const` variables). You'd want your code to use them directly at runtime, and you certainly do not want to have a call to the `sqrt` or `pow` function that is basically useless because you already know the result at compile time.

If you want to be *sure* that there is no useless calls, you should use the macros with C pre-processor for this. And you are not wrong, the C compilers can sometimes make us *feel in the 80s*. There is many other more modern programming languages available.

**However** as the compilers are getting more modern at optimizing prorgrams it is also possible that the compiler might inline functions then pre-compute them at compile time. The only way to know if it is possible is to test and look at the generating assembly. For instance in my test program :

```
static inline int twice(int x)
{
    return 2*x;
}

int main()
{
    int i = twice(2);
    i += twice(4);
    printf("Result is %d\n", twice(i));
    return 0;
}
```

Compiles with latest gcc and `-Os` turned on to :

```
main:
    sub     rsp, 40
    .seh_stackalloc 40
    .seh_endprologue
    call    __main
    lea     rcx, .LC0[rip]
    mov     edx, 24
    call    printf
    xor     eax, eax
    add     rsp, 40
    ret
```

As you can see, the result, 24 is pre-computed in the assembly code. With `double` type it's less obvious to proove because of how floating points number doesn't immediately appear in the assembly, however I checked and the optimisation is also made. Then **it is not neccessary to use the C pre-processor for constants anymore**. But if you want performance, *always check the assembly code*.

Comment: Also, do not use `PIPI` it is offending in french :)

Answer (score 2):

Without [`-ffreestanding`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options) and the like, Gcc computes them at compile-time, at least with optimizations turned on. So there is unlikely to be a function call.

If `-ffreestanding` is used, I don't see a better way than defining the constants manually for cases like `sqrt`, if a self-made inline function turns out to be insufficiently fast. Gcc's [`const` attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes) may help to avoid re-computations (but I guess Gcc can infere that on its own if the definition is visible).

The question said they should be computed by the preprocessor. I don't see a reason for this, the only thing one can do with floating-point constants in the preprocessor, is to stringify or concatenate them. If this is really needed, they need to be hard-coded, too. An inline function also cannot be called by the preprocessor.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use constants which makes the compiler aware of it. 
And pick more explicit names for your constants.

```
const float SQRT_OF_3 = 1.7320508;
const float PI_SQUARE = M_PI*M_PI;
```